# How to calibrate my touchscreen on a HP Pavilion tx2500?

Tags: laptop, hardware, tablet, hp-pavilion

I have a laptop (HP Pavilion tx2500) with touchscreen functionality, it works fine but isn't calibrated, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: What touch screen model do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Quotation from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1478728#4

The `10-wacom.conf` file that is referenced is the one in `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

> The calibration for a TX2500's stylus
>   is:
>
> Option      "TopX"      "225"
>     Option      "TopY"      "225"
>     Option      "BottomX"   "26300"
>     Option      "BottomY"   "16375"
>   The calibration for a TX2500's touch is:
>
> Option      "TopX"      "200"
>     Option      "TopY"      "225"
>     Option      "BottomX"   "4000"
>     Option      "BottomY"   "3875"
>   The calibration for a TX2z's stylus and touch is:
>
> Option      "TopX"      "0"
>     Option      "TopY"      "0"
>     Option      "BottomX"   "9600"
>     Option      "BottomY"   "7200"
>   You can add that to the 10-wacom.conf, or if that
>   fails to a section in xorg.conf.  I
>   think the wacom driver is suppose to
>   auto-calibrate your device.  Often
>   Xorg.0.log in /var/log has the
>   coordinates when the driver initiates
>   the device.
>
> The [Rotation HOW TO](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6274392&postcount=1) has scripts.
>   Just remember there has been a change
>   in the device name conventions.  Enter
>   'xinput --list' in a terminal to get
>   the new device name and substitute it
>   in the scripts (with the quotes) where
>   it says stylus or touch, etc.  You can
>   also use the device ID numbers.

Comment: Can't you just go to the Wacom settings item in Control Center?